# Export instance, ParentNode, Value to chain of events lists

Tags: c#, list, powershell, csv

I have a powershell script that exports an `Instance`, `ParentNode`, and `Value` to a list which I export to CSV file. I run this on multiple machines and append them to a master list.
Example:

```
Server1
Instance        ParentNode          Value
----------------------------------------
InstanceA       BatchName           BatchX
InstanceA       SourceFolderPath    \\server\feeds\BlahBlah
InstanceA       DestinationLocation \\Server\archive\BlahBlah
InstanceA       DestinationLocation \\Server\consumption\BlahBlah
InstanceA       BatchName           BatchT
InstanceA       SourceFolderPath    \\server\feeds\i.BlahBlahFailed
InstanceA       DestinationLocation \\Server\archive\i.BlahBlahFailed
InstanceA       DestinationLocation \\Server\consumption\BlahBlahFailed

ServerB
----------------------------------------
InstanceC       BatchName           BatchX
InstanceC       SourceFolderPath    \\Server\archive\i.BlahBlahFailed
InstanceC       DestinationLocation \\Server\archive2\BlahBlah
InstanceC       DestinationLocation \\Server\consumption2\BlahBlah
```

Now that times like 100 more times with some of the `SourceFolderPaths` are destinations on other servers. The ultimate goal is to be able to get a list of a feeds path so from start to finish. Any language is fine C#, PHP, etc...

Comment: Assuming you're only using the SourceFolderPaths I've got an answer for you.

Comment: What is the actual question you would like answered?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to tackle this:

```
        string[] input = File.ReadAllText("textfile3.txt").Split(new string[1] { "SourceFolderPath" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 1; i < input.Count(); i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(input[i].Substring(0,input[i].IndexOf("Instance") - 1).Trim());
        }
```

If reading the whole file into memory is undesirable you can iterate through the file like this:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("textfile3.txt");
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            int index = line.IndexOf("SourceFolderPath");
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line.Substring(index + 16).Trim());
            }
        }
```

I used the listbox items collection to store the paths.  You could easily use a List to store them as well.